# Set traditional property in AJAX shorthand methods

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to set the Tradition property for Ajax shorthand commands such as `$.post()` & `$.get()`?

I know its possible to set it with the following

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    traditional: true,
    }
});
```

However, I would to do this with the shorthand version.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible, but I think you are looking for  [jquery.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) method.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: What options specifically are you trying to set ?

Comment: traditional param handling is my guess, which can be done through ajaxSetup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way seems to be

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
    traditional:true
   });
```

But that will be applied to all your (future) ajax queries.

`$.post` or `$.get` are "shorthand Ajax functions", without any "options" parameter.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible but sometimes the jQuery documentation leaves a few things out. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible since

for eg. `$.post()` is [equivalent to](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Source code for `$.get` and `$.post`:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L779

You'll need to use [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) for additional options

Comment: @Phrogz thanks for the cite, I got it from [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)